# What does "the manuscript has been removed from your Associate Editor Center" mean?

Tags: publications, editors

I received the following email:

> Dear Prof. X:
>   You are no longer assigned to manage the review of Manuscript ID #####. The manuscript has been removed from your Associate Editor Center.

What does it mean? I sent the paper 2 months ago and just today I got the email above. Do I have to wait long as a new editor will check the manuscript?

Comment: Is this in response to a paper you submitted, or one you were supposed to referee?

Comment: Also, are you Prof. X? Does the manuscript ID match yours?

Comment: This question is highly unclear. It seems like this message got into your mailbox by mistake.

Answer (score 2):

From its wording this e-mail is intended for the associate editor managing the manuscript in question. Thus unless you are an associate editor of said journal and were the editor assigned to the paper in question, this mail is not intended for you. Therefore you should not have received this e-mail. That you did receive it anyway means that something went wrong. Contact the journal and tell them what happened.